# Configuring Let's Encrypt on Tomcat 8 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt, tomcat8

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 VM running in Google Compute Engine. The VM is assigned a static IP, which is configured in my DNS entry for www.myapic.com .

I have tomcat 8 running as the webserver. Now I want to configure Let's Encrypt with it and I have no idea how this works. I am a UI developer and completely new to this. I also searched few places but didn't find any tutorial. Is there any documentation that will guide me to set HTTPS up for my domain.

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/ You need any web service binding at 80 port. Example for nginx: location ~ /.well-known/ { root /var/www/cerbot; }

Answer (score 2):

As @Alexander Makarenko points out, you need to configure [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuother-apache). The [help page](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuother-apache) will walk you through the steps to configure the certbot-auto for Apache Tomcat. Make sure to follow all the way to the bottom so that your SSL certificates automatically renew.

Comment: Thank you for your ans. I did read that help page earlier. But didn't find any place where I am specifying my domain name. Without the domain name how is it going to configure ssl? am I not missing anything?

Comment: It depends on the SSL cert you are using. Certbot automates the process for you so it is not necessary. It will update the necessary Apache files on your behalf. If you have your domain name is not configured in your Apache config files, the setup will prompt you for it.